# How does will the regex works in my PHP code?

Tags: php, regex

I have this piece of code, actually, I don't know anything about *Regex*, however I want to know what will this code do and if I wrote it right.
If the user only type letters and numbers, in the variable *$username*, that is used to collect the data in the field, then do something as login. Else, tell the user that he can't type symbols as !@#$% in the field. Please, is it right?

```
if(preg_match('[A-Za-z0-9]', $username)){
    //Do something good, as login
}else{
    //Do something bad, as show error message
}
```

Comment: Test your code in a PHP sandbox, such as this one: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: Or test it at https://3v4l.org/ or test it on your machine. Just test it yourself.

Comment: There's also [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), where it also explains what is checked, what was found, etc.

Comment: I didn't have success, I think I really need to study more and read something about Regex. However, I loved that websites, is really amazing, interesting and helpful! Thank you all, I will use this websites to learn more!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing checks if the variable $username is alphanumeric.  Using only letters (lowercase or uppercase) and numbers.  Then
// Do something good, as login

if NOT then will
// Do something bad, as show error message

To help with regex you can try [Regex Gen](https://www.regular-expressions.info/regexmagic.html)

Comment: Worth pointing out that these are only ASCII Latin letters.

Comment: I learned a little bit of Regex after read something in the internet. Thank you for post, it helped me.

Comment: Thank you, Dharman!